# How to remove and replace another value in curly braces via Regex in C#?

Tags: c#, regex

I have an XML document from a customer. They have XML files similar to the following one:

```
<id>{1}</id> <Name>{2}</Name> <Detail>{3}</Detail>
```

I want to replace `{1} -> 123456`, `{2} -> "mike"`, `{3} ->"Hummer"`.

```
foreach(customer customer in List){  "find {1} and replace customer id etc..." }
```

How can I do that with regex?

Comment: If you already have a Customer, would it be simpler to use `string.Format("<id>{0}</id> <Name>{1}</Name> <Detail>{2}</Detail>", customer.Id, customer.Name, customer.Details)`? If this is not possible, can you provide some more detail around what your data looks like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using XML, you hardly need any regex for setting the tag values with pre-defined strings. Use `XElement`:

```
var xmltxt = "<root><id>{1}</id> <Name>{2}</Name> <Detail>{3}</Detail></root>";
var doc = XElement.Parse(xmltxt);
foreach (var id_node in doc.Elements("id"))
   id_node.Value = "123456";
foreach (var name_node in doc.Elements("Name"))
   name_node.Value = "mike";
foreach (var detail_node in doc.Elements("Detail"))
   detail_node.Value = "Hummer";
Console.WriteLine(doc.ToString());
```

Output:

```
<root>
  <id>123456</id>
  <Name>mike</Name>
  <Detail>Hummer</Detail>
</root>
```

And just in case you insist on a regex way (if you happen to deal with some invalid XML, as a fallback):

```
var rx = new Regex(@"(?<=>)\{\d+\}(?=<)");
var dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
dict.Add("{1}", "123456");
dict.Add("{2}", "mike");
dict.Add("{3}", "Hummer");
Console.WriteLine(rx.Replace(xmltxt, m => dict[m.Value]));
```

Perhaps, @fubo's solution is even better for a fallback *unless* you need to replace `{...}`s strictly inside some tags.

Answer (score 3):

This xml looks like a format parameter for String.Format...
Do you really need a (complicated) regexp ?

Can't you do something like that ?

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var f = "<id>{1}</id> <Name>{2}</Name> <Detail>{3}</Detail>";
        var str = String.Format(f, null, "123456", "mike", "Hummer");
        Console.WriteLine(str);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

output

```
<id>123456</id> <Name>mike</Name> <Detail>Hummer</Detail>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
string doc = "<id>{1}</id> <Name>{2}</Name> <Detail>{3}</Detail>";
Dictionary<string, string> sDict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
sDict.Add("{1}", "123456");
sDict.Add("{2}", "Hummer");
sDict.Add("{3}", "foo");

foreach (var item in sDict)
{
    doc = doc.Replace(item.Key, item.Value);
}
```